# Unity does not load when selecting Xorg open source radeon driver

Tags: unity, ati, graphics, xorg, radeon

When I select the X.org Radeon open source driver, Unity **does not** load. However, when I select the Proprietary AMD Driver from the official Ubuntu repository, Unity **does** load. Why is Unity doing this? I had no problems with switching between these drivers in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. This started happening when I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10.

Before I ever installed the propriatery AMD driver, the X.org driver loaded Unity fine, but very sluggishly. I downloaded the AMD driver from their official website and installed that first and that is what started this problem. I removed that driver and went back to X.org and X.org didn't load Unity either. Then using Synaptic, I installed the AMD driver from the Ubuntu repositories and thats what I'm using now. I'm very confused why that downloaded AMD driver would effect X.org.

I have a AMD Radeon HD 6620G. It's integrated graphics on my AMD A8-3500M Fusion APU (Accelerated Processing Unit as AMD advertises it). Here is a Wikipedia article on my A8 Fusion APU [Here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Fusion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This likely happens because you have a card that is not well supported by the open source drivers (which are still under a heavy state of flux in their development, especially with newer cards).

If Unity does not detect certain features in your driver, or encounters a bug, it will fail to load. This is why you would have to use the proprietary drivers.

To determine the exact problem, you can run Unity from a terminal (even on a TTY) and see what output it gives you with either driver. If it is crashing with the Open Source drivers you will most likely see "segfault" or something similar, and if it fails to load it will report why.

With this information in hand, you can then report a bug using `ubuntu-bug unity`, and describe what information you got on the command line output in your bug report.

Comment: It certainly sounds like my AMD card is not supported very well. When I use the x.org open source drivers, the mouse pointer studders and lags when loading Ubuntu and Unity, but the proprietary drivers have no studdering or lag. When I start Ubuntu, the open source drivers have graphical glitches and I have to restart several times before the login screen loads properly. The proprietary drivers load it fine. The proprietary drivers also load Ubuntu faster than x.org open source oddly enough.

Comment: I updated my proprietary drivers and the x.org drivers from the xorg edgers ppa. Both drivers now load Unity, but on xorg, it still studders when loading something heavy like virtualbox and it still has graphical glitches on startup, so I still have to restart several times. Also, now that I updated the proprietary drivers and currently using that, it now displays a watermark in the right lower corner of the screen that says "AMD Unsupported Hardware".